# create my own wordpress themes and cant accese to style file

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to create my own wordpress theme. I created a php file where i put my html code is on for home page and I try to link the style file for some reason it does not work.
I create the folder of my theme in the theme folder in bitnami.
Inside my theme folder there is an index.php, front.php, style.css file.
That I enclose a link to bootstrap it does work but it does not read my own style file.
I upload the theme folder using wordpress control panel
here is how I called to the style file :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content\themes\timor\style.css">
```

this is the path to my theme folder:**

```
C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.6.2-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes
```

What am I doing wrong?

I would be happy if anyone can help me !

*this is my html code in the front.php page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content\themes\timor\style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);">

  <div id="page" class="site">

    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </nav>
       
      <p class="headline">

      </p>
      <p class="first-pr">
      </p>
      <p class="readmore">
        <button class="readmorebtn" type="button"> /></button>
      </p> 
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
      <p class="headline2">

        </p>
    </div>


  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

my style sheet is :

```
/*
Theme name: Timor
text domain: Timor
Version: 1.0
description: Timor 
Author: Timor1
*/

.container{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 970px;
  background: #272737 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  opacity: 0.8;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-size: cover;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.headline{
font-size: 53px;
top: 290px;
left: 927px;
width: 852px;
height: 78px;
text-align: right;
font: normal normal bold 53px/62px Heebo;
letter-spacing: 0px;
direction: rtl;
color: #FFFFFF;
opacity: 1;
margin-right: 141px;
margin-top: 290px;
}

.first-pr{
  width:713px ;
  height: 211px;
  float: right;
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 141px;
  top: 406px;
  left: 1066px;
}

.container2{
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 90%;
height: 970px;
opacity: 0.8;
direction: rtl;
align-items: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.headline2{
top: 1070px;
left: 826px;
width: 268px;
height: 73px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 0px;
color: #06AAE2;
opacity: 1;
font-size: 50px;
align-items: center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using backslashes instead of forward slashes and you are missing a backslash before wp-content, so your code should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/timor/style.css">
```

Also, this is not the recommended way to include a stylesheet in WordPress (though it should work).  See this article for more info, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/